# Debug a custom service host factory in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I created a new WCFServiceLibrary using VisualStudio 2015. I executed it and all is fine, I can see the WCF Test Client with the sample methods and I can access from the browser.

Now I want to add a custom service host factory. I added this class:

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary1
{
    public class DerivedFactory : ServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);

            // do something here

            return host;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I added the serviceHostingEnvironment section to the app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

<serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <serviceActivations>
    <add service="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1"
          relativeAddress="./MyService.svc"
          factory="WcfServiceLibrary1.DerivedFactory"/>
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>

    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

I put a breakpoint in the method CreateServiceHost in the DerivedFactory class. I execute the project, but:

- I do not enter in the breakpoint
- I can not access from the browser to: http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/MyService.svc

I already tested with relativeAddress="/MyService.svc" and relativeAddress="MyService.svc", but this do not work.

There is a way to test the custom factory in debug mode?

Service class:

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary1
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This specific answer is simple, and involved in a redundant configuration. In order for us to understand more, I've elaborated my answer.

**By an IIS Hosted Service** the correct way to reach your service is the following URL http://localhost:8733/MyService.svc
Which is mandated by

```
<add service="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1"
    relativeAddress="./MyService.svc"
    factory="WcfServiceLibrary1.DerivedFactory"/>
```

**Only in Self Hosted Service** you will need the **baseAddress** configuration, therefor it is redundant and can be removed.

```
<host>
  <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/" />
  </baseAddresses>
</host>
```

In case you want to reach the full address http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/ you will need to change **relativeAddress** to the following:

```
relativeAddress="./Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/MyService.svc"
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Maybe my question was too simple, I just wanted to test my custom service host in debug mode, using WCF Service Host (WcfSvcHost.exe).

Comment: While I was rewriting my question I found this other question:
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543327/forcing-wcfsvchost-exe-to-use-my-custom-service-host)
I think it is not possible to force WcfSvcHost.exe to use my custom service host.
So, for debug my solution, I must use self-hosting?

Comment: You can't use your WCF Service Host without proper configuration for your service. Thus, i urge you to read the answer again and align you configuration.

Comment: I understood that my relative Address was configured incorrectly. I changed it like you tell me but even like this the WCF Service Host does not see my custom service host factory.

Comment: @RobertoCarlos, Verify the name of your service concrete class is `Service1`.

Comment: I just added the service class to my question. My project is the sample project that you have when you create a new WCFServiceLibrary using VisualStudio 2015. Then I added the factory class and the  serviceHostingEnvironment section to the app.config. These are all my changes.